# eclipse as a dual (or more) programming env

Tags: eclipse

I want to set up eclipse on my computer so it could handle C++, Java and maybe more in the future, all in the same package.

I haven't found a way to do so other than have two separate folders, each with it's own eclipse env.

A friend did that and has both running as separate programs no problem. I tried the same and the C++ eclipse keeps throwing errors that it can't compile.

Is there a way to have the one eclipse and have it do multiple things ? If not, what should i do about that error stuff ?

Thanks,
Yonatan

forgot to add the error:

(Cannot run program "make" (in directory "D:...\cpp-workspace\test"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified)

Comment: Would help if you gave us the errors.

Comment: Considered asking your friend to show you how to set it up?

Comment: ^ i've done what he did. doesn't work. I guess there is something not related to eclipse itself.

Answer (score 1):

You can install Eclipse CDT as a plugin in a standard Eclipse

Google 'eclipse cdt  plugin' or [check out this instructions](http://www.nws.noaa.gov/oh/hrl/developers_docs/Eclipse_CDT_plugin.doc)

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide a separate C++ compiler as eclipse does not come with one. On *nix this will probably be gcc, on Windows you can use mingw.